# Set multiple buttons.Content in a for (each) loop

Tags: c#, wpf, list, foreach

Edit:

8 years later, don't use this method !

Invest your time in learning about WPF and data binding.

Need to know where this question came from? Click the edit button.

Comment: What about putting your buttons in a list or array instead of giving them similar names? This is the purpose of arrays

Comment: why not just bind the `SPItems` to an `ItemsControl` full of `Buttons`?

Comment: This initial process is max. 8 values (8 buttons), if another button is pressed, the next 8 values will be retrieved from my database...

Comment: there seem to be some misunderstandig i think.. I already have my buttons, i just need their content to be set from the list `Button1.Content = "my value1";` `Button2.Content = "my value 2";` etc...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks to [WiiMaxx](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1993545/wiimaxx) i found the solution !

With using [this method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/1993545) i succesfully set my buttons text with data retrieved from my database.

It became a `foreach` loop, but now it works exactly as needed. **edit: found the `for` version**

I have a `WrapPanel`, which contains my `buttons`, in which again contains my `TextBlock's`.

Because my `TextBlock's` don't start with `0` but with `1` (ex: `SubItem1txt`) i needed to create an extra `int`. I hope this will be usefull for someone.

Thanks to everyone :) !

#### foreach version:

```
int i = 1;
int a = 0;
foreach (string spi in SPItems)
    {
        WrapPanel pnl = UIHelper.FindChild<WrapPanel>(this, "SubItems");
        Button btn = UIHelper.FindChild<Button>(pnl, "SubItem" + i);
        TextBlock tb = UIHelper.FindChild<TextBlock>(btn, "SubItem" + i + "txt");
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        tb.Text = SPItems[a];
        a++;
        i++;
    }
```

#### for version:

```
    int i = 1;
    for (int a = 0; a < SPItems.Count; a++)
    {
        WrapPanel pnl = UIHelper.FindChild<WrapPanel>(this, "SubItems");
        Button btn = UIHelper.FindChild<Button>(pnl, "SubItem" + i);
        TextBlock tb = UIHelper.FindChild<TextBlock>(btn, "SubItem" + i + "txt");
        btn.Visibility = Visibility.Visible;
        tb.Text = SPItems[a];
        i++;
    }
```

Answer (score 2):

If your Buttons Named like Button1,Button2,Button3....

you could use `FindChild<T>()`
 
[here you get the method](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1759923/1993545)

```
for(int i =0; i< SPItems.Count;i++) // iterates for each item in your SPItems
{
     Button foundButton =  UIHelper.FindChild<Button>(Application.Current.MainWindow, "Button"+i);

     if(foundButton != null) //Protecteted agains trying to use Null-Reference
     {
          var foundButtonTextBlock =foundButton .Content as TextBlock

          if(foundButtonTextBlock != null)//Protecteted agains trying to add Text by Null-Reference
               foundButtonTextBlock.Text  = SPItems[i];
     }
}
```

### Edit

**as normal way:**

```
 for(int i =0; i< SPItems.Count;i++) // iterates for each item in your SPItems
    {
         TextBlock foundTextBlock =  UIHelper.FindChild<TextBlock>(this, "SubItem"+1+i+"txt");

         if(foundTextBlock != null) //Protecteted agains trying to add Text by Null-Reference
         {
              foundTextBlock .Text  = SPItems[i];
         }
    }
```

**as Painful way:**

```
int i =0;
if(SPItems.Count >0)
{
    SubItem1txt.Text = SPItems[i]; 
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >1)
{
    SubItem2txt.Text = SPItems[i];
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >2)
{
    SubItem3txt.Text = SPItems[i];
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >3)
{
    SubItem4txt.Text = SPItems[i]; 
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >4)
{
    SubItem5txt.Text = SPItems[i]; 
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >0)
{
    SubItem6txt.Text = SPItems[i];
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >5)
{
    SubItem7txt.Text = SPItems[i];
    i++;
}
if(SPItems.Count >6)
{
    SubItem8txt.Text = SPItems[i];
    i++;
}
//..... never ever do this
```

Comment: If i had more rep, i'd gave you a +1, because this answer helped me the most. I needed to use this in my `for loop:` `SubItem1txt.Text = SPItems[i]; i++;` AND `SubItem2txt.Text = SPItems[i]; i++;` etc.. Of course, i have 8 buttons to be filled.. now if `SPItems.Count` has an index less than 8, an exception is thrown. Can i somehow say `if (SPItems.Count == 1) =>> fill 1 button` OR `if (SPItems.Count == 2) =>> fill 2 buttons` ? Thanks btw !!

Comment: @DeMama what exeption you gat? because if you just copy past it  and replaces `TextBlock` with `Button` the only trouble could be if you have 7 Buttons and `SPItems.Count>7` then you will get a `NullReferencExeptoin` because it doesn't check if `foundButton != null`

Comment: i found the solution, thanks for your help, i posted an answer :) cheers !

Answer (score 1):

Do NOT manipulate UI elements in code for these simple tasks. This is the WPF way to do what you're asking:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication4.Window18"
        xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
        xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
        Title="Window18" Height="300" Width="300">
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding}">
        <ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
            <DataTemplate>
                <Button Content="{Binding}" Margin="2"/>
            </DataTemplate>
        </ItemsControl.ItemTemplate>
    </ItemsControl>
</Window>
```

Code Behind:

```
using System.Windows;
using System.Linq;

namespace WpfApplication4
{
    public partial class Window18 : Window
    {
        public Window18()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            DataContext = Enumerable.Range(0, 20).Select(x => "Item" + x);
        }
    }
}
```

This is what it looks like in my screen:

[image]

Comment: Hmm ok.. But i already have my buttons.. I just want to set the `content` or `text inside those buttons`

Comment: @DeMama then create a proper ViewModel to hold your `string` values and bind the `Buttons` `Content` property. `<Button Content="{Binding SomeStringInTheViewModel}"/>`

Answer (score 0):

This is sort of a dirty solution but if you're going to be manipulating all the buttons on the form it's worth it. The simplest way that I know of is to add all the buttons to an `ArrayList` (yes, manually, that's the painful part) and then just looping over that list.

Comment: Or a `List<Button>` instead of `ArrayList`.

Comment: @MD.Unicorn yeah, originally I just said 'list' but `ArrayList` has a lot better performance so I decided to state it specifically. Obviously there there are a few data structure that would work fine here.