# Replace button name letter in a loop

Tags: c#, for-loop

I am writing a code in C# for developing a Windows Phone 8 App.

I have 8 Buttons named ( f1 ,f2 ,f3 ...... f8)

Now, I want to add their Text value into an array. I know how to do this
but it will take 8 lines of code.

Example:

```
Numbers[0] = Convert.ToInt32(f1.Content);
Numbers[1] = Convert.ToInt32(f2.Content);
.
.
.
Numbers[7] = Convert.ToInt32(f8.Content);
```

Is there a way to write a loop to make all this process for me? Something like this:

```
for(int i=0; i < 8 ; i++)
    Numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(fX.Content);
```

where X starts with the Value 1 (f1) and then 2 and so on.
Is there any way I can do that in C#?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! I have edited your title. Please see, "Should questions include “tags” in their titles?", where the consensus is "no, they should not".
http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Comment: possible duplicate of [Set multiple buttons.Content in a for (each) loop](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15420157/set-multiple-buttons-content-in-a-for-each-loop)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a grid control with the name `MainGrid` (it doesn't *have* to be a grid control, anything will work. Just adjust your code accordingly)

```
int[] numbers = MainGrid.Children.OfType<Button>()
            .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Content)).ToArray();
```

Here's some example XAML that goes with the above code

```
<Grid x:Name="MainGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
        <RowDefinition />
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>
    <Button Grid.Row="0" Grid.Column="0" Content="1" x:Name="F1" />
    <Button Grid.Row="1" Grid.Column="0" Content="2" x:Name="F2" />
    <Button Grid.Row="2" Grid.Column="0" Content="3" x:Name="F3" />
    <Button Grid.Row="3" Grid.Column="0" Content="Do not count me" />
</Grid>
```

As LordTakkera pointed out in the comments, this code would fail if you had other buttons in the same parent container that you *didn't* want to get the value of. In such a case, you'd need an additional `Where()` clause, which would look like this:

```
int[] numbers = MainGrid.Children.OfType<Button>()
            .Where(x => x.Name.Contains("F"))
            .Select(x => Convert.ToInt32(x.Content))
            .ToArray();
```

Since LINQ can be confusing and unclear if you're not familiar with it, here's a more traditional way of doing the same thing:

```
//Unless you have a specific reason for wanting an int array, a list is easier to work with
List<int> numbers = new List<int>();

//Use .OfType<>() So that you don't have to cast each control to a button in the loop
foreach(Button button in MainGrid.Children.OfType<Button>())
{
    //If it's not one of our named buttons, continue the loop
    if(! button.Name.StartsWith("F")) continue;

    int buttonValue = Convert.ToInt32(button.Content);
    numbers.Add(buttonValue);
}
```

Comment: Note that this only works if these are the ONLY buttons on the grid. You would need a "where" clause on the name if there are others.

Comment: That's true. Good call

Comment: @Jedediah what is X ?

Comment: In this case `x` is a local anonymous variable. In basic terms, it's the "current" button. To make it clearer, this could be written like this: `.Select(button => Convert.ToInt32(button.Content))` `x` is just typical short-hand when using LINQ

Comment: +1, this is a good answer, though LINQ seems a bit overkill perhaps :)

Comment: @Jedediah what .ToArray() does ?

Comment: `.ToArray()` Converts the returned `IEnumerable<int>` that `.Select()` returns into an integer array. You could also call `.ToList()` if you wanted a `List<int>` instead of an array. That probably made it less clear, if you're not familiar with LINQ and generics...

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming you are in your code-behind, since you "could" use the control names.

To do this, use the FindName function ([MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-US/library/windowsphone/develop/system.windows.frameworkelement.findname%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)):

```
for(int i=0; i < 8 ; i++)
    Numbers[i] = Convert.ToInt32(((Button)FindName("f" + i)).Content);
```

This isn't a very XAML/WPF/MVVM way of doing this, so you might want to look at setting up an items control bound to a list of the numbers (that you could then call sum on), but this should work for the posted scenario.

Comment: A textBox casting ? , but am dealing with buttons , not TextBoxs

Comment: Missed that part, sorry. Fixed! The concept is the same though, I just did the wrong cast.